Find distribution of random variable constructed by expectation of another random variable
Consider a r.v $Y$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq s)=\frac{\mathbb{E}\mathbb{I}_{\{X\leq s\}}e^{tX}}{\mathbb{E}e^{tX}}.$$
I am supposed to find the distribution of $Y$ explicitly if
(i) $X$ ~ Ber($p$) and
(ii) $X$ ~ U([$0,1$]). My idea so far for both is as follows: Since
$$\mathbb{I}_{\{X\leq s\}}=0,\  s<0$$
$$\mathbb{I}_{\{X\leq s\}}=1,\ s\geq1$$
we obtain
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq s)=0,\ s<0$$
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq s)=1,\ s\geq1$$
Im confused how to evaluate the expecation in the case of $0\leq s<1$. can someone help me out there?

First, let's assume $X = \operatorname{Ber}(p)$, that is, $\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1-p$ and $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = p$. Since $s < 1$, $\{X \leq s\} = \{X = 0\}$. Now notice that \begin{equation} \mathbb{I}_{\{X \leq s\}}e^{tX} = 1 \iff X = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbb{I}_{\{X \leq s\}}e^{tX} = 0 \iff X = 1,\end{equation} so that $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{\{X \leq s\}}e^{tX}] = 1 \times (1 - p) + 0 \times p = 1 - p.$ Now $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = pe^t + 1 - p$ and then we have \begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(Y \leq s) = \frac{1 - p}{1 - p(1 - e^t)}.\end{equation}
If $X = \operatorname{U}([0,1])$, then we know that the density of $X$ is constant and equal to $1$, so \begin{equation}\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{I}_{\{X \leq s\}}e^{tX}] = \int_0^s e^{tX}\phantom{.}dX = \frac{e^{st} - 1}{t},\end{equation} and since $\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}] = \frac{e^t - 1}{t}$ we have \begin{equation}\mathbb{P}(Y \leq s) = \frac{e^{st} - 1}{e^t - 1}.\end{equation}

Now I understand the method, thank you for explaining!

@Mathisnothealthyforu I've added the uniform case. If you find that this is an acceptable answer and it solved your problem, you can click the checkmark under the votes to mark the question as answered.

@LucasGiraldi. Your final result for the Bernoulli case is doubtful, because it is independent of $s$, while $\Bbb{P}(Y \le s)$ is nothing else than a truncated generating function of $X$ with respect to $s$. It would imply by the way that $\Bbb{P}(Y \le s) \neq 0$ for $s < 0$.

It doesn't depend on $s$ precisely because ${X \leq s} = {X = 0}$, since $X$ is Bernoulli distributed it can only takes values $0$ or $1$ and we want $X \leq s < 1$, so $X = 0$. Now, notice that I'm assuming also that $s \geq 0$. Of course, if $s < 0$ then ${X \leq s} = \varnothing$. But this case was alredy covered by @Mathisnothealthyforu.

@LucasGiraldi. Okay, I see. I missed the fact that you were working with $s \ge 0$ from the start, my bad.
